# in android jsonarray cannot be converted in jsonobject

Tags: php, android

The script fetches data from phpmyadmin but android studio cause this error

> of type org.json.Jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject

[image]

my code android

[image]

code

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code please, where you try to parse `json` data?

Comment: as screen you send, your json string is a jsonArray and start with '[' you shouldn't parse that with json object

Comment: fyi, `phpmyadmin` is just a tool to manage MySQL databases/queries etc. - you don't fetch data from it. Also, I'd remove the `PHP` tag since it is completely irrelevant here

Comment: i have upload code please tell me solution

Comment: Please don't post code, errors or other text as images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are getting `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject` from your server. So, You have to parse the array first then you can get object from it.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

     String id = jsonObject.getString("id"); 
     String m_e = jsonObject.getString("M_E"); 
}
```

Comment: sir but i want to fetch one data at a time so how can i fetch ..link image url in view one link not list..

Comment: If you want to get one data at a time then you have to change it from your server side. Currently server provide array `[]` type instead of object `{}` type.

Comment: how can i write object data from script sir?? please help sir

Comment: What is the problem of above approach? If you return one data from server then it iterate once and give you single data

Comment: sir my project is verify slip so teacher will fetch slip from database an teacher will verify it i set the button on imageview which send the value to attendance 
table present or absent